# Save a sliced point cloud- Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I have sliced a point cloud(30%) from original cloud(.ply image) using Matlab R2015b Image Processing Toolbox. When i save that sliced cloud as a new point cloud.

sliced and background of original both are saved. How can i just store sliced part as a new point cloud (.ply)

```
stepSize = 1;
indices = 1:stepSize:(cloudImage.Count)/2;
pt = select(cloudImage, indices);
pcwrite(cloudSliced,'half','PLYFormat','binary');
```

[image: Save Red Part only]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it appears that the sliced point cloud is stored in `pt`.
So it should be

```
pcwrite(pt,'half','PLYFormat','binary');
```